# UIActivityIndicatorView (spinner) in UITableViewCell cannot start animating by UITableViewController in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a custom UITableViewCell containing a UIActivityIndicatorView (spinner), and I try to click on the cell so that spinner starting to animate. So I try to implement following in UITableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testcase", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestCaseTableViewCell
    cell.spinner.startAnimating()
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

I have the instance variable "spinner" in my TestCaseTableViewCell(custom cell class):

```
@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

But it didn't work......

I just want to click on the cell, and the spinner starts to animate cause I want to do something in this period. While the something is done, I can show something like "OK" in the cell(as the same position of the spinner). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with how you are retrieving your cell from the table view: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. This method asks the `UITableView` for a cell from its reuse cache when you need a new cell to display, so should only be used in the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method of your table view's data source.

To ask the table view for an *on-screen* cell, use `cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. Your code sample then becomes:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? TestCaseTableViewCell {
        cell.spinner.startAnimating()
    }
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple method:

- Select your UIActivityIndicatorView and check "Animating" in **the attribute inspector**

[image]

- Check "hidden"

[image]

- Now do this:

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testcase", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestCaseTableViewCell

      cell.spinner.hidden = false    // <== Here

      tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  }
  ```

Don't forget to hide the unhidden UIActivityIndicatorView if needed ;)