# How to start animation of UIActivityIndicatorin in tableViewCell with Swift?

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uitableview

hope you are well.

I am trying to activate an UIActivityIndicator on specific cell of my tableview.  I want to hide labels, images, buttons and show other elements instead of. One of these elements is an UIActivityIndicator which appears but doesn't animate :(

Here the code used :

```
    func showProgressViewInCell(path: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = self.toursUITableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as! ToursTableViewCell;

    // stop userInteraction
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = false;

    // hide elements
    cell.downloadTourButton.hidden = true;
    cell.descriptionLabel.hidden = true;
    cell.typeOfTourLabel.hidden = true;
    cell.typeOfTourImage.hidden = true;
    cell.distanceOfTourLabel.hidden = true;
    cell.distanceOfTourImage.hidden = true;
    cell.durationOfTourLabel.hidden = true;
    cell.durationOftourImage.hidden = true;
    // show progressbar, percent, activityIndicator and updateLabel
    cell.percentLabel.hidden = false;
    cell.downloadTourProgressView.hidden = false;
    cell.updateLabelProgressBar.hidden = false;
    // downloadInProgressActivityIndicator uses option hides when stopped
    cell.downloadInProgressActivityIndicator.hidden = false;
    cell.downloadInProgressActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

    // reload data of tableview
    self.toursUITableView.beginUpdates();
    self.toursUITableView.reloadData();
    self.toursUITableView.endUpdates();
}
```

Here the configuration on InterfaceBuilder of my UIActivityIndicator :

[configuration of UIActivityIndicatorView on Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZnT7.png)

This didn't worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494991/6188918

In advance thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I made an app which displayed activity indicator inside a cell. I did it by calling `startAnimating()` inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of data source. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alexander Doloz,

in fact before call my function :

```
func showProgressViewInCell(path: NSIndexPath) {...}
```

I had to animate my UIActivityIndicator on cellForRowAtIndexpath method like that :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // custom cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.defaultCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ToursTableViewCell;

    //start animating ProgressActivityIndicator
    cell.downloadInProgressActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

    self.configureCell(cell, indexPath:indexPath);

    return cell;
}
```

and like that it's working well.

Many thanks,